# Function removes extra spaces but leaves one space between words in a char pointer

Tags: c, function, space

I need a function that will take a char pointer like char *s  = "abc   def gf    ijklmn". If it is passed through the function int space_remove(char *) it should return the number of extra spaces and modify the string and take out the extra spaces.

```
int space_remove(char *s)
{
    int i = 0, ic = 1, r = 0,space = 0;
    //char *sp = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) * sizeof(char));
    char sp[256];
    while (*(s+i) != '\0'){
        if (*(s+i) == ' ' && *(s+i+1) == ' '){
            space = 1;
            r++;
        }
        if (space){
            sp[i] = *(s+i+r);
            i++;
        }

        else if (!space){
            sp[i] = *(s+i+r);
            i++;

        }
        else {
            sp[i] = *(s+i+r);
            i++;
        }
    }
    sp[i+1] = '\0';
    printf("sp:%s \n",sp);
    s = sp;
    //free(sp);
    return r;
}
```

any help here?

if the the string is "abc (10 spaces) def (20 spaces)   hijk" it should return "abc(1 space) def (1 space) hijk"

Comment: OT: As always `i` < `i+r` all `sp` can be replaced by `s`. Which allows to parse strings longer then 255 characters.

Comment: OT^2: On behalf of readabiltiy just decide whether to use `*(s+x)` or `s[x]` notation to addess an array's element. It's up to you which one, but just do not mix both.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues

1. Reset `space` to `0` in `while` loop.
2. Do not return `sp` in as it is local char array. You can copy string in `s` instead.

   strcpy(s, sp);

instead of

```
s = sp;
```

`strcpy` would be safe as length of `sp` should be at max length of `s` when there is nothing to trim.

Comment: i reset space to 0
and i did strcpy

but it does not take away extra spaces

Comment: @KeyMaker, I think you need to relook at your logic. Your code halves the spaces. Generally, the logic is if you find space, skip more spaces (do not put them in `sp`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int space_remove(char *s)
{
    char *s1=s;
    int count=0;
    while(*s){
        *s1++=*s++; // copy first even if space, since we need the 1st space
        if(*(s-1) == ' '){ //if what we just copied is a space
            while(*s ==' '){
                count++;
                s++; // ignore the additional spaces
            }
        }
    }
    *s1='\0'; //terminate
    return count;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //char *str="hi     how r     u";
    int count=space_remove(argv[1]);
    printf("%d %s",count,argv[1]);
}
```

The modified answer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int space_remove(char *s)
{
    char *s1=malloc(strlen(s)*sizeof(char));
    char *s2=s1; // for printing
    int count=0;
    while(*s){
        *s1++=*s++; // copy first even if space, since we need the 1st space
        if(*(s-1) == ' '){ //if what we just copied is a space
            while(*s ==' '){
                count++;
                s++; // ignore the additional spaces
            }
        }
    }
    *s1='\0'; //terminate
    printf("%s",s2);
    return count;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *str="hi     how r     u";
    int count=space_remove(str);
    printf("\n%d",count);
}
```

Comment: You should put the s1++ and s++ after the if statement, to make the code easier to read.

Comment: i tried it and it didn't work for and I am suppose to return how many extra spaces

and it seg faults at this line - *s1++=*s++;

Comment: It works just fine in my computer (i have tried in two, a mac and a windows). I have added the whole code. What it the input for which it is giving the segmentation fault? What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am compiling on a linux machine using gccx
i just used gcc and it still gave me a seg fault.

Comment: I found the problem. If you compile with the new edit it works on linux machine. run with `./a.out "adasd     asdas    "` The problem is when you assign a string to a `char *` it converts it to `const char *`. I am trying to find out how to fix it.